# Reading .Rda file in Pandas throws an LibrdataError error

Tags: dataframe

I have a data stored in .Rda format which I want to upload on Python pandas to create a data frame.I am using pyreadr library to do it. However, It's throwing up an error -

LibrdataError: Unable to convert string to the requested encoding (invalid byte sequence)

Answer (score 0):

Your data is in an encoding different from utf-8. pyreadr supports only utf-8 data. Unfortunately nothing can be done to fix it at the moment. The limitation is explained in the [README](https://github.com/ofajardo/pyreadr#known-limitations) and also tracked [in this issue](https://github.com/ofajardo/pyreadr/issues/64)

Comment: Is it possible to convert to UTF-8?

Comment: You would need to convert all strings to UTF-8 using R and save the file again before opening it with pyreadr